# Confusión al elegir credenciales para un proyecto de Google

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics

Estoy intentando crear las credenciales para un proyecto de Google con las siguientes características:

1. Utilizará la API de Google Analytics para acceder únicamente a los datos un usuario (yo mismo)
2. El objetivo es presentar estadísticas de mi sitio web en mi propio sitio web

Cuando intento crear las credenciales en la consola de Google, **no sé que tipo de credenciales necesito** y le pido a Google que me ayude.

Ellos me van preguntando y yo lleno lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo ¿?  no tener duda en las primeras dos preguntas... pero la tercera es todo un misterio: **¿A qué tipo de datos accederás?**

Ambas opciones son totalmente confusas, para mí:

- **Datos de usuario**: *Accede a datos pertenecientes a un usuario de Google (con su permiso)*
- **Datos de aplicación**: *Accede a datos pertenecientes a tu propia aplicación*

Según el uso que pretendo darle, descrito al principio de mi pregunta, diría que la opción correcta sería **Datos de aplicación**. O sea, yo quiero autorizar permanentemente mediante esas credenciales a presentar ciertos datos de Google Analytics en mi sitio.

Alguno me preguntará ¿y por qué no eliges esa?

Cuando elijo esa, me pregunta lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No uso ninguna de las dos, así que elijo la última opción. Entonces me dirige a esta pantalla donde ya me quedo totalmente perdido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta sería entonces:

**¿Qué tipo de credenciales necesito para un proyecto que se ejecutará en el servidor (hosting compartido) mediante PHP y que presentará datos del mismo usuario (yo)**

**¿Cómo dar una autorización permanente para ese proyecto, que sea leída de algún archivo por ejemplo?**

Comment: Se me escapó de nuevo @Rubén. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima, *la segunda es la vencida*. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude resolverlo.

Indico aquí cómo lo hice por si puede servir a otros.

Las indicaciones se encuentran en el enlace [Hello Analytics API: inicio rápido en PHP para las cuentas de servicio](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php).

En efecto, para tener un acceso sin tener que autorizar a cada cliente, hay que configurar una cuenta de servicio, descargar un archivo (generalmente JSON), que deberá residir en el servidor y que el código en el servidor leerá cada vez que sea requiera.

Los pasos son los siguientes:

### Paso 1: habilitar la API de Analytics

#### 1.1 Crear un proyecto (si no lo tienes creado)

Hay que tener creado un proyecto en la consola de Google (no me detengo en cómo hacerlo para no hacer la respuesta demasiado larga).

#### 1.2 Crear un ID de cliente

1. Abre la página [Service accounts (Cuentas de servicio)](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts). Si se te solicita, selecciona un proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí eliges, a la derecha, **`Seleccionar`** o **`Crear`**, según quieras crear la cuenta de servicios para una proyecto que ya existe o crear un nuevo proyecto. Si no tienes proyectos creados primero te guiará hacia la creación de tu primer proyecto.

Suponiendo que ya hay algún proyecto creado, pulsamos en **`Seleccionar`** y aparece una pantalla con todos los proyectos, para elegir uno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Al seleccionar nuestro proyecto podremos crear la Cuenta de Servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haz clic en **Create service account** (Crear cuenta de servicio).

3. En la ventana **Create service account** (Crear cuenta de servicio), escribe el nombre de la cuenta de servicio y selecciona **Furnish a new private key** (Suministrar una nueva clave privada). Si quieres [conceder autoridad en todo el dominio de G Suite a la cuenta de servicio](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority), selecciona también **Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation** (Habilitar delegación de todo el dominio de G Suite). A continuación, haz clic en **Create** (Crear).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El nuevo par de claves pública/privada se genera y se descarga en el equipo, lo que sirve de copia única de esta clave. Eres responsable de almacenarla de forma segura.

En la imagen, verás que a la derecha he seleccionado `Lector` en la opción **`Función`**. La misma sirve para asignar tipos de privilegios a la cuenta que estamos creando. Como para este caso sólo interesa leer datos, he asignado esa función.

> Cuando se te pida el tipo de clave, selecciona JSON y guarda la clave
>   generada como **`service-account-credentials.json`**. La necesitarás
>   en el tutorial.

El archivo json se descarga en nuestro equipo tan pronto pulsamos en `Crear`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 1.3 Agregar la cuenta de servicio a la cuenta de Google Analytics

> Esto era básicamente lo que no estaba haciendo en mi caso

La cuenta de servicio recién creada tendrá la dirección de correo electrónico **`<projectId>-<uniqueId>@developer.gserviceaccount.com`**. Utiliza esta dirección para agregar un usuario a la cuenta de Google Analytics a la que quieras acceder a través de la API. Para este tutorial solo se necesitan los permisos Leer y analizar.

> **NOTA:**
>
> La información del párrafo anterior no es del todo cierta. Por ejemplo
>   en mi caso, la dirección de correo electrónico no termina por
>   `@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
>
> **Lo que hay que hacer aquí es copiar el valor de la columna `ID de la cuenta de servicio` que aparece a la derecha de la cuenta que acabamos
>   de crear, en la consola de proyectos de Google.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora **tenemos que abrir sesión en Google Analytics** y crear un nuevo usuario con los datos copiados anteriormente, seleccionando la opción **`Administración de Usuarios`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el nuevo panel que se abrirá, pulsamos en el signo de **`+`** que se encuentra en la parte superior derecha y luego en **`Añadir Usuarios`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se abrirá un nuevo panel.

Donde dice `Introducir direcciones de correo electrónico` pegaremos la dirección que copiamos en la consola de Google, aquella relativa a nuestra cuenta de servicio.

Más abajo, activaremos los permisos pertinentes. Para el caso que nos ocupa, se han activado los permisos: **`Leer y analizar`**.

Finalmente, pulsaremos en el botón **`AÑADIR`**, situado en la parte superior derecha. Y nuestro usuario de proyecto quedará añadido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Paso 2: Instalar la biblioteca de cliente de Google

Para obtener la [biblioteca de cliente de las API de Google para PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), [descarga la versión](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#download-the-release) o utiliza la herramienta [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

### Paso 3: Configurar el código de muestra

Se podrá usar el [código de muestra que ofrece Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/samples/service-php.txt), o cualquier otro, para empezar a usar las funciones de Google Analytics en nuestra web...

> **MUY IMPORTANTE:** El archivo `service-account-credentials.json` que se ha descargado al crear la Cuenta de Servicio, deberá estar bien
>   guardado en nuestro servidor. Aunque Google dice que lo guardemos en
>   la misma carpeta donde está el archivo php, recomendaría guardarlo en
>   una carpeta oculta, y si es posible fuera del root. Lo que sí hay que
>   tener en cuenta es indicar en el código la ruta exacta donde se
>   encuentra ese archivo.

### Paso 4: Ejecutar la muestra

Después de haber habilitado la API de Analytics, de haber instalado la biblioteca de cliente para PHP de las API de Google y de haber configurado el código fuente, la muestra estará lista para ejecutarse.